# grub2 not showing triple boot

Tags: 14.04

I have a win 8 lap on which I I
Installed Kali Linux on a separate
Partion then I installed Ubuntu alongside Linux and when my hardisk was of mbr partion it was perfectly working but when I changed my partion to gpt and did exactly the same installation grub 2 is not showing and I have a uefi boot

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling grub on your machine.

1. Create a bootable ubuntu USB or CD installed. (Same installed release recommended)
2. Boot from that LIVE USB/CD and install boot-repair :-

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
   ```
3. Then run `boot-repair` or On dash search for **boot repair**  and select **recommended settings**.

Comment: If you have UEFI boot, you should install all systems in UEFI boot mode and not have a boot loader in the MBR. Boot all systems and live installers in UEFI mode, never BIOS mode. If Boot-Repair does not restore UEFI boot, then post Summary report above. All systems must be in same boot mode for grub to show them.